# MVC Paging not working in AJAX Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, paging

I am trying to implement ASP.NET MVC Paging using [MVC4.Paging](http://mvcpaging.apphb.com/) nuget package.

**Problem:**
It is working in online demo and also in the download source code. However I am not able to find why it is not working in my particular project by *AJAX*. In my project it is working by full post back method but not Ajax.

I have even tried to copy over the `Index` action method and `Index` and `_AjaxEmployeeList` Views (.cshtml) files (except .js).

Note: In my solution its not bootstrap as shown in samples. Also my controller name is `AdminController` whereas in Samples its `HomeController`

In my solution I need it to work in AJAX method as in samples.

*Kindly help regarding:

1. How to find the root cause for why it is not working?

2. How to make this working?*

.
**My Solution Code (which I tried to reproduce in my solution from the sample):**

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using MvcPaging
@model IPagedList<MvcPagingDemo.Models.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MVC 4 Paging With Ajax Bootstrap";
}
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <h2>
            Ajax Paging With Bootstrap In MVC 4
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            The pager also supports area's. @Html.ActionLink("Ajax paging in an area", "Index", "Admin", new { Area = "AreaOne" }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Admin",
                            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "grid-list", HttpMethod = "get", LoadingElementId = "loading", OnBegin = "beginPaging", OnSuccess = "successPaging", OnFailure = "failurePaging" },
                            new { id = "frm-search" }))
{
    <div class="input-append">
        <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" name="employee_name" placeholder="Name" />
        <button class="btn" type="submit">
            <i class="icon-search"></i>&nbsp;Search</button>
    </div>
    <div id="grid-list">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_AjaxEmployeeList", Model); }
    </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">

    function beginPaging(args) {
        // Animate
        $('#grid-list').fadeOut('normal');
    }

    function successPaging() {
        // Animate
        $('#grid-list').fadeIn('normal');
        $('a').tooltip();
    }

    function failurePaging() {
        alert("Could not retrieve list.");
    }

</script>
```

**_AjaxEmployeeList.cshtml**

```
@using MvcPaging
@model IPagedList<MvcPagingDemo.Models.Employee>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Phone
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Phone
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.City
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="pager1">
    @Html.Raw(Ajax.Pager(
            new Options
            {
                PageSize = Model.PageSize,
                TotalItemCount = Model.TotalItemCount,
                CurrentPage = Model.PageNumber,
                ItemTexts = new ItemTexts() { Next = "Next", Previous = "Previous", Page = "P" },
                ItemIcon = new ItemIcon() { First = "icon-backward", Previous = "icon-chevron-left", Next = "icon-chevron-right", Last = "icon-forward" },
                TooltipTitles = new TooltipTitles() { Next = "Next page", Previous = "Previous page", Page = "Page {0}." },
                Size = Size.normal,
                Alignment = Alignment.centered,
                IsShowControls = true,
                IsShowFirstLast = true,
                CssClass = ""
            },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "grid-list",
                OnBegin = "beginPaging",
                OnSuccess = "successPaging",
                OnFailure = "failurePaging"
            }, new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", employee_name = ViewData["employee_name"] }))
    <div class="well">
        Showing <span class="badge badge-success">@Model.ItemStart</span> to <span class="badge badge-success">@Model.ItemEnd</span>
        of <span class="badge badge-info">@Model.TotalItemCount</span> entries</div>
</div>
```

**AdminController.cs**

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private const int defaultPageSize = 3;
    private IList<Employee> allEmployee = new List<Employee>();
    private string[] name = new string[4] { "Will", "Johnny", "Zia", "Bhaumik" };
    private string[] phone = new string[4] { "1-274-748-2630", "1-762-805-1019", "1-920-437-3485", "1-562-653-8258" };
    private string[] email = new string[4] { "donec@congueelitsed.org", "neque.non@Praesent.co.uk", "et.magna@Pellentesque.ca", "enim.commodo@orci.net" };
    private string[] city = new string[4] { "Wigtown", "Malderen", "Las Vegas", "Talence" };


    public AdminController()
    {
        InitializeEmployee();
    }

    private void InitializeEmployee()
    {
        // Create a list of 200 employee.
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            var employee = new Employee();
            //int categoryIndex = i % new Random().Next(1, 5);
            //if (categoryIndex > 3)
            //    categoryIndex = 3;
            index = index > 3 ? 0 : index;
            employee.ID = i + 1;
            employee.Name = name[index];
            employee.Phone = phone[index];
            employee.Email = email[index];
            employee.City = city[index];
            allEmployee.Add(employee);
            index++;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string employee_name, int? page)
    {
        ViewData["employee_name"] = employee_name;
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
        IList<Employee> employees = this.allEmployee;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee_name))
        {
            employees = employees.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
        }
        else
        {
            employees = employees.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower() == employee_name.ToLower()).ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
        }



        //var list = 
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("_AjaxEmployeeList", employees);
        else
            return View(employees);
    }

    public ActionResult Paging(string employee_name, int? page)
    {
        ViewData["employee_name"] = employee_name;
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
        IList<Employee> employees = this.allEmployee;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee_name))
        {
            employees = employees.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
        }
        else
        {
            employees = employees.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower() == employee_name.ToLower()).ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
        }

        return View(employees);
    }
}
```

**JS references in the _Layout.cshtml**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

Since I was using `jquery-1.11.1.js`, in script file `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` I had to replace calls to [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

But simple find and replace was not right way which I found later. I found from other sources that I have to change completely those lines of code as the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) works.

I replaced the code as below:

Non-working code with [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function:

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
    debugger;
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});

$("form[data-ajax=true] input[type=image]").live("click", function (evt) {
    debugger;
    var name = evt.target.name,
        $target = $(evt.target),
        form = $target.parents("form")[0],
        offset = $target.offset();

    $(form).data(data_click, [
        { name: name + ".x", value: Math.round(evt.pageX - offset.left) },
        { name: name + ".y", value: Math.round(evt.pageY - offset.top) }
    ]);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(form).removeData(data_click);
    }, 0);
});

$("form[data-ajax=true] :submit").live("click", function (evt) {
    debugger;
    var name = evt.target.name,
        form = $(evt.target).parents("form")[0];

    $(form).data(data_click, name ? [{ name: name, value: evt.target.value }] : []);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(form).removeData(data_click);
    }, 0);
});

$("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    debugger;
    var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (!validate(this)) {
        return;
    }
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method || "GET",
        data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
    });
});
```

Working code with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "form[data-ajax=true] input[type=image]", function (evt) {
    var name = evt.target.name,
        $target = $(evt.target),
        form = $target.parents("form")[0],
        offset = $target.offset();

    $(form).data(data_click, [
        { name: name + ".x", value: Math.round(evt.pageX - offset.left) },
        { name: name + ".y", value: Math.round(evt.pageY - offset.top) }
    ]);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(form).removeData(data_click);
    }, 0);
});

$(document).on("click", "form[data-ajax=true] :submit", function (evt) {
    var name = evt.target.name,
        form = $(evt.target).parents("form")[0];

    $(form).data(data_click, name ? [{ name: name, value: evt.target.value }] : []);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(form).removeData(data_click);
    }, 0);
});

$(document).on("submit", "form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
    var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (!validate(this)) {
        return;
    }
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method || "GET",
        data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not described how exactly it is not working. but i will guess the most common issues which might be causing  your issue

1. make sure you actually have a reference to the correct java script files. its not enough to have them in a folder, your page must link to them.

see the following link to see how you reference scripts on you page.    http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

make sure you put in the correct path.

make sure you reference the *ajax.js files for ajax to work along with any other required files.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that it is not working in ajax manner. It is working by full post back method. Secondly I have included most of the js files shown in screenshot by bundling. To reduce the question size I have not posted the `BundleConfig.cs` and `_Layout.cshtml`. However I am going to try once more tomorrow when I will be at office.

Comment: If its working in full post back then that would indicate that you have not included the ajax files, make sure that the page where the ajax is being called is referencing the layout page.